# Android GUI not displaying properly in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am creating gui in relative layout and reason i am using relative layout is that, i am using a fakeview in the middle of the screen to align all the other objects properly in the center of the screen. But the output on my mobile is completely different and is completely stretch out.

My problem  is that the black line in the middle is supposed to be just 1dp in height, still it appears as 50dp in height on my device. Also there is huge gap in the middle below exchange rate and above discount amt($). Such problems weren't there in the emulator. the entire screen is divided into two parts, the lower part and upper part and there is gap in middle.

I am using nexus 4 running stock rom 4.4.2 to test my application.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFE0">

    <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/carat"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/cut3"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_above="@+id/caratrs"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"


        android:layout_below="@+id/carat"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

        android:layout_above="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView" />

    <Spinner
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shape2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/color"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cut3" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cut3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shape2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cut3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clarity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shape2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shape2"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/converter"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/converter"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/discamt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_above="@+id/price"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/caratrs"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rap Price"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discount(%)"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/converter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exchange Rate"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/converter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discount Amt($)"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/price"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PPC($)"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"

        android:layout_above="@+id/caratrs"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ppcrs"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/Rs"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Carat :"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/carat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Here is the screen shot]

Comment: Could you please clarify where is the problem ? for me I use table layout http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/ when I want to implement something similar to this .

Comment: The black line in the middle is supposed to be just 1dp in height, still it appears as 50dp in height on my device. Also there is huge gap in the middle below exchange rate and above discount amt($). Such problems weren't there in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your black view remove

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
```

You'll end up with the following:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/converter"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/view" />
```

You're already anchoring the view to **converter**

So you don't need the extra anchor.

Comment: i did that and thank, it did change the huge black line to its normal size but still the huge gap in middle is still there. Can you suggest me how shall i remove it??

Comment: All the views below the black line should switch from `layout_above` to `layout below` and reference the views above them.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you not to use the fake view, from the screenshot, it is better to use linearlayout to hold blanks in the screen, and each blank you can use a relativelayout, in this way, this layout will look well in all devices

Comment: can you clarify it more?? i am not able to understand exactly how am i suppose to do it.

Comment: you should do something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751094/how-to-create-a-neat-two-columns-input-form-in-android

Comment: so i should be using linearlayout for each line??